# Opauth Login via Social networks

Tags: php, facebook, oauth, linkedin-api

I am using https://github.com/uzyn/opauth
I always get the following error notice:

**Notice**: No strategy is requested. Try going to https://mietabhishek.redirectme.net/mobile/za/live to authenticate with Live in **C:\wamp\www\mobile\za\lib\Opauth\Opauth.php** on line **125**

Here the 'live' accordingly changes to the name which I mention last in Strategies, suppose if I add facebook's strategy at the end of opauth.conf.php , it will show:

**Notice**: No strategy is requested. Try going to https://mietabhishek.redirectme.net/mobile/za/facebook to authenticate with Facebook in **C:\wamp\www\mobile\za\lib\Opauth\Opauth.php** on line **125**

Although the opauth works perfectly, but on jQuery Mobile's websites it makes problem. And also the error doesn't looks good on production websites.

Please help, thanks,

Comment: Similar discussion here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/opauth/IYcRbWwsVIM/EbSWF72lQl8J

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this issue due using and older library. Not sure since this is a bit older but try looking at that github page and download the newest library and try again. There were some changes to the code that caused this for me.